# Check if message exists return it - regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have regular expression like this:

"error 1|error 2|error 3|error 4|error 5"
about 80 (can be more) miscelanous error messages

Now I check if in my text error message exists:

```
Regex errorRegex = new Regex("error 1|error 2|error 3|error 4|error 5");
if (errorRegex.Match(content).Success)
          return "ERROR";
```

But now I need return which message was in content for example "error 4" Can I do this in one match? What is the best way (optimized for performance) to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this by keep a temporary variable of type `Match`:

```
Regex errorRegex = new Regex("error 1|error 2|error 3|error 4|error 5");
Match match = errorRegex.Match(content);
if (match.Success)
          return match.Value;
```

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think this answer answers what the asker was asking, even though the askers approach might not be optimal. So +1.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can simplify your regex statement greatly if there is a standard error message output:

```
Regex errorRegex = new Regex("error ([0-5]{1-2}).*");
```

Your error messages should look like, for example "error 42: blah blah".

Then error messages are easy to parse for their number.

Then just have a case condition for the error number.

The value inside the braces will be in group 1, and will be a number from 0 to 5.
Check for matches, and extract the group if a match was found like so:

```
MatchCollection MatchList = errorRegex.Matches(content);
Match firstMatch = MatchList[0];
int errNum;
if(firstMatch && firstMatch.Groups[0] && firstMatch.Groups[1]){
    errNum = (int)firstMatch.Groups[1];
}
```

Otherwise, if you are parsing someone else's error messages, then just return the message you found back from your function, and write a switch statement to handle each error code, like so:

```
void ErrorFunction(string content){
    [...]
    Regex errorRegex = new Regex("error 1|error 2|error 3|error 4|error 5");
    Match rMatch = errorRegex.Match(content);
    if (rMatch.Success)
              return rMatch.Value;
}
```

Then elsewhere:

```
switch(ErrorFunction(content)){
    case "error 1":
        DoSomething();
        break;
    case "error 2":
        DoSomething();
        break;
    case "error 3":
    case "error 4":
    case "error 5":
        DoSomething();
        break;
    default:
        DoSomething();
        break;
}
```

Comment: the value inside the parentheses would be group 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not just first check for the presence of `error 4`, then return?

It sounds like you're trying to prematurely optimize your code. Have you profiled it?

If anything, putting more complicated checks into a regular expression is going to slow things down more. Keep your code and logic simple, and run profiling after that.

Comment: I must check for error message at web page - so error messages can be miscellaneous, I don't know other way to check if the page contains error message and what message is it so I put all knwo messages in regular expression

Comment: @TheBigO: Then he turns it into one giant if...else and ends up on The Daily WTF. :-D

Comment: also, if there is a different behavior for most error messages, then a switch statement is the best you can do anyway.